# not able to generate proper change log using liquibase

Tags: liquibase

If Table is having multiple indexes along with composite index then liquibase is not able to generate change log file.

Ex. suppose table is having 8 indexes which is comprised of single column index and multiple column index(composite index) then liquibase is not able to generate all indexes but we are getting successful completion message of change log.

&

Is there any order that we need to take care  while generating change log 
like
--difftypes="tables,columns,indexes,foreignkeys,primarykeys,uniqueconstraints,data"

Is this order OK?

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: What DB are you using? What version of liquibase? What do the indexes look like (SQL definition)? Which of the indexes are generated which are not?. The better your narrow down the problem, the more likely it is to get answers. :) (I don't think that the order is important for this).

Comment: Thanks Jens for your gentle reply.I am using mysql and version of liquibase is 3.0.1. if is single column index or three column index then it is able to generate XML for the corresponding DB but if it is 2 column index then it is neither failing nor giving exception. I am getting succesfull completion message but in the XML file that is been generated is not having  XML for the 2 column index field.

Comment: I think you still need to add more info to your question so that the problem can be reproduced. E.g. add the definition of the table and the indexes in question. Then others can try to reproduce your problem.